# Universal quantifier introduction seemingly follows all rules, yet, it doesn't

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

I am asked to prove $(\forall x):[P(x)\rightarrow Q(x)]$ from the two premises $(\forall x):[P(x) \rightarrow (Q(x) \vee R(x))]$ and $\neg[(\exists x):[P(x) \wedge R(x)]]$.

I replicated my paper attempt on Fitch, a Logic proof checker. Fitch tells me my last step of universal introduction is not a logical step. I am struggling to see why this is the case, especially since I've used this step in seemingly the same manner countless times before, and, my step follows the universal introduction rule, namely:

$$\dfrac{\boxed{x_0 \\.\\.\\.\\\phi[x_0/x]}}{\forall x \phi} \forall x \text{ i}$$

My attempt at the proof and the Fitch error is shown below. The prompt advises me that the step in question "is of the wrong form". May anyone advise on what I did wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must begin the subproof for a *universal introduction* with an *arbitrary* assumption.   That is just a declaration of the local variable without any further assumptions about it.

Line 3 is not an arbitrary assumption. It has an added assumption of $P(a)\to(Q(a)\lor R(a))$.  Do not do that.

You will want to derive $P(a)\to(Q(a)\lor R(a))$ separately from the declaration of the variable, using universal elimination of line 1.

$${\begin{array}{|l}~~3~.~\boxed a\\\hline~~4'.~ P(a)\to(Q(a)\lor R(a))\quad\forall\mathsf E~1\\~~\vdots\\16'.~P(a)\to Q(a)\end{array}\\17'.\forall x~(P(x)\to Q(x))\qquad\quad~~\forall\mathsf I~3{-}16'}$$

Comment: I don't like cluttering threads with comments, but this is just a great answer. Thank you very much. With the arbitrary assumption, the proof is now accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\neg\exists x(P(x) \wedge R(x)) \iff (\forall x):[\neg P(x) \vee \neg R(x)].$

Using Universal Instantiation, we get that $\neg P(a) \vee \neg R(a)$ for some arbitrary $a.$

Also, using the same rule, you conclude that $P(a) \to (Q(a) \vee R(a)).$

Using the material implication, you get $\neg P(a) \vee Q(a) \vee R(a).$

Adjuntcion rule yields $[\neg P(a) \vee \neg R(a)] \wedge [\neg P(a) \vee Q(a) \vee R(a)].$

From the distributive rule follows $\neg P(a) \vee [\neg R(a) \wedge (Q(a) \vee R(a))].$

*Modus Tollendo Ponens* tells you that $\neg P(a) \vee Q(a).$

Finally, using the Material Implication again, you get $P(a) \to Q(a).$

Since $a$ is an arbitrary element, you use Universal Generalization to conclude that $(\forall x):[P(x) \to Q(x)].$

Comment: How did you use Modus Tollendo Ponens? That part was unclear to me.

Comment: *Modus Tollendo Ponens* $-$ $(P \vee Q) \wedge \neg P \implies Q.$ I used it to conclude $Q(a)$ from $\neg R(a) \wedge (Q(a) \vee R(a))$

Comment: So shouldn't it be $\neg P(a)\lor [[\neg R(a)\land (Q(a)\lor R(a))]\color{red}{\implies} Q(a)]$ instead of $\neg P(a)\lor [\neg R(a\land (Q(a)\lor R(a))]\color{red}{\implies}\neg P(a)\lor Q(a)$?

Comment: Why would you exclude $\neg P(a)?$ I’m just using this rule of inference to simplify the expression between $[$$]$

Comment: Because the implication is only on that part. I give you another example. We have $(p\land q)\to(r\land s)$. We know that $a\land b\to a$ by simplification. However, we CAN'T say by simplification $[(p\land q)\to(r\land s)]\to [p\to r]$ because it is not a tautology. It should be $[(p\land q)\to p]\to[(r\land s)\to r]$.

Comment: I just check the truth table to see if I was wrong and the conclusion is that we can apply the *Modus Tollendo Ponens* like I did. It is a tautology

Comment: Yes you are right. But why sometimes is a tautology and sometimes not?

Comment: That is a really good question.. I think that follows from the way we construct our logical system, but I can’t give you a concrete answer (although is a really nice question)

Comment: I think I know why sometimes is true and sometimes not. The example of $(p\land q)\to(r\land s)$ does have a $\to$. However, in your deduction it has $\lor$. That's why in my example it fails and in yours it doesn't. We could also say $[(p\land q)\lor(r\land s)]\to(p\lor r)$ (which is useful) OR $[(p\land q)\to p]\lor[(r\land s)\to r]$ (which is not so useful).

Comment: I didn't consider that $p\to q\equiv\neg p\lor q$.